# Unable to dispatch JSP Page

Tags: jsp, jsf, jdeveloper

I have got the following exception when trying to run any jsp page in my application.
When I tried to run it in another machine with the same jdeveloper version it works well.

Any ideas about this problem ?

I work on jdev 10.1.3.3.0

The error message:

```
12/02/01 13:03:27 Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.3.0)  initialized

Feb 1, 2012 1:03:27 PM oracle.jsp.logger.JspMessages infoCannotDispatchJspPage
INFO: **Unable to dispatch JSP Page : Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException:** 

D:\jdevstudio10133\jdev\system\oracle.j2ee.10.1.3.41.57\embedded-oc4j\default-web-app\tcwm7\faces\pages\startup\index.jsp (The system cannot find the path specified)

Feb 1, 2012 1:03:29 PM oracle.wireless.its.ra.TelnetResourceAdapter run
INFO: Industrial Telnet Server version: Version 10.1.3.0.0 started-up successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path is probably configured wrong

the error you get is

> (The system cannot find the path specified)

In this line

```
D:\jdevstudio10133\jdev\system\oracle.j2ee.10.1.3.41.57\embedded-oc4j\default-web-app\tcwm7\faces\pages\startup\index.jsp (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

So you probably need to configure it.

Hope this helps